# FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions: fromViewController: handler: completion not called on app first run

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, ios10, fbsdkloginkit

I have a Facebook login-enabled app and for some reason `FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions: fromViewController: handler:` is not called on the very first run of my app after installation. If I just kill my app (even without trying to login to Facebook or do anything: trying to login on first open or not doesn't change anything) and open it again, it works perfectly.

Why?

(I've checked the view controller passed to the method is not nil and is the current view controller)

Here is my login code:

```
+(void)loginWithFacebookWithCompletion:(ULCompletion)completion{
    [[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init] logInWithReadPermissions:FACEBOOK_READ_PERMISSIONS fromViewController:[ULMasterViewController instance] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if(result.token){
          ...
        }
[...]
```

The rest is irrelevant as the completion block is not called at all (not even with an error). I've got the `FACEBOOK_READ_PERMISSIONS` hardcoded:

`#define FACEBOOK_READ_PERMISSIONS (@[@"user_friends", @"user_birthday", @"email", @"user_photos"])`

And finally, `[ULMasterViewController instance]` is valid (not nil, and has its view in hierarchy (otherwise it complains about view not being in hiearchy, also tried that)).

Comment: Have you written - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application       openURL... method in your appdeligate.m file?

Comment: @SatishMavani Yes. and it has the appropriate call the FBSDKLoginManager, yet it's not called in either case (either on the "failing" first run, nor the successful login in second run)

Comment: Have you created a custom action for login with facebook button?

Comment: @SatishMavani what do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: I mean, Have you used FBSDKLoginButton for login with facebook?

Comment: @SatishMavani No, I have my custom button that calls the method, as the Facebook button doesn't fit the look & feel of my app's design.

Comment: Can you post some beginning part of your method which called on click of your facebook button?

Comment: @SatishMavani see my updated question.

Comment: Okey, this is not much relevant but try by creating FBSDKLoginManager object separately as i have done same and working for me.

 FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

Comment: + Also make sure that you have set “fbauth2” value for key “LSApplicationQueriesSchemes” in your info.plist file

Comment: @SatishMavani that was it: putting the login manager to a strong reference (as contrary to inline `alloc init`ing solved the issue. I really wonder why it wasn't working on first try but working at subsequent runs, but anyway, it solved the problem.

Comment: @SatishMavani you can post your answer as an answer (not a comment) so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This working in  my case .

1 .Create instance of FBloginManager in interface.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *manager
```

2 .Initialise  in ViewDidLoad.

```
manager = [FBSDKLoginManager new]
```

3 .And finally call login permission method using this instace of FBLoginManager.

Comment: Oh you meant initializing the instance in the class scope, yeah, that worked.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this ***exact*** problem and it was very frustrating.  The key to fixing it turned was that my app code was making lots of concurrently existing FBSDKLoginManager objects.  Refactoring my code to use a singleton shared instance (as opposed to running `[FBSDKLoginManager new]` all over the place) eliminated this bug/issue for me.

Mysteriously, I never understood why this worked.  I used the debugger to trace into the FBSDK code, and the only (very) mysterious issue I found was that from inside the `loginWithReadPermissions` method, the `fromViewController` parameter was being set to `nil` even though I was passing in a non-`nil` value.  *Strange*...

Answer (score 0):

This is not much relevant but try by creating FBSDKLoginManager object separately as i have done same and working for me.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
```

Comment: I think it's not about creating only separately, but creating at class/global scope as opposed to method scope. Probably, the Facebook SDK is holding a weak reference to the manager and it's being released as soon as the function returns, thus, being nil at callback time.