# Swift 3 facebook login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I've now tried to follow the complete guide of [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login) however i keep getting an error when i try to build.

The error i get is `type of expression is ambigous without more context` on this line `LoginManager.logIn([.PublicProfile], viewController: self) { loginResult in`

I've

I've started with putting into pod

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

and then run `pod install`

after this i've imported this into my viewController

```
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin
```

i've then added a UIButton to `viewDidLoad`

```
let myLoginButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
myLoginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
myLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 40);
myLoginButton.center = view.center;
myLoginButton.setTitle("My Login Button", for: .normal)
```

then i've added following function to the viewController

```
@objc func loginButtonClicked() {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    LoginManager.logIn([.PublicProfile], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .Failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .Cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .Success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it is working fine in Objective C.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089906/3901620

initialise in ViewDidLoad

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
```

use this instance on button click event.

```
func loginButtonClicked() {
    loginManager.logIn([.PublicProfile], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .Failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .Cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .Success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the instance variable you created to call the "logIn" method. Instead you are trying to call "logIn" on the LoginManager class.

Replace

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
LoginManager.logIn([.PublicProfile], viewController: self) { loginResult in
```

With

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
loginManager.logIn([.PublicProfile], viewController: self) { loginResult in
```

Comment: i did nothing changed

Comment: Replace ".PublicProfile" with ".publicProfile"