# Facebook login in iOS is not opening safari when attempting to login for the first time

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, fbsdk

My app **Login Screen**,

[image]

On first attempt facebook login button doesn't open safari browser whereas on second attempt it works fine.

Below is my tried code:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [FBSDKLoginManager new];
manager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser;
NSArray *permissions = @[@"email",@"public_profile"];
[manager logInWithReadPermissions:permissions fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error){

    if(error) {
        [self showAlertWith:@"Oops!" message:@"Login Failed, try again" handler:nil];
        return;
    }
    if(result.isCancelled) {
        [self showAlertWith:@"Oops!" message:@"Login Failed, try again" handler:nil];
        return;
    }else {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                           parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture, name, email"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id userinfo, NSError *error) {
             if(!error) {
                 if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                     [self makeGraphRequest];
                 }
             }else {
                 EKLog(@"error %@", error);
             }
         }];
    }
}];
```

Clicking login button for the first time the `loginWithReadPermission` is called but callback block is never called, whereas clicking again, the callback handler is called. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089906/3901620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one solution if it work!

declare `FBSDKLoginManager *manager` as instance variable or property and initialize it in `viewDidload` like,

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [FBSDKLoginManager new];
```

And then use!! It might be happened because of local declaration!